# Переключение кнопок

Tags: javascript

При переключении с одной на другую кнопку должно работать по принципу кнопок ,если нажал на первую то в ней записалось 1 ,а во второй кнопке 0 и наоборот если нажал на вторую ,при нажатии записалась 1 ,то тогда в первой 0 .Пока что у меня только цвета меняются поочередно ,а 1 и там и там записывается .

```js
let result2 = 0;
let myEvent2 = function() {
  if (result2 == 0) {
    document.getElementById('test2').style.backgroundColor = '#3aff3a';
    result2 = 1;
    document.getElementById('test3').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result3 = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('test2').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result2 = 0;
    document.getElementById('test3').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result3 = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = result2;
}

// СКРИПТ для кнопок вкл, выкл
let result3 = 0;
let myEvent3 = function() {
  if (result3 == 0) {
    document.getElementById('test2').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result2 = 0;
    document.getElementById('test3').style.backgroundColor = '#3aff3a';
    result3 = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('test2').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result2 = 0;
    document.getElementById('test3').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
    result3 = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('result3').innerHTML = result3;
}
```

```html
<!--кнопка КОМАНД. -->
<button id="test2" onclick="myEvent2()"><p id="text2">КОМАНД.</p></button>
<div id="result2">0</div>

<!--кнопка ОТПУСК -->
<button id="test3" onclick="myEvent3()"><p id="text3">ОТПУСК</p></button>
<div id="result3">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче ты забыл добавить ссылку на резльтат2 к скрипту 1  а результат3 к скрипту 2.

```html
<button id="test2" onclick="myEvent2()">
    <p id="text2" style="position:absolute;color:black;top:6px;left:30px;font-size:30px;">КОМАНД.</p>
</button>

<div id="result2">0</div>

<!--СКРИПТ   для кнопок вкл, выкл -->

<script>
    let result2 = 0;
    let myEvent2 = function()
    {
        if (result2 == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('test2').style.backgroundColor = '#3aff3a';
            result2 = 1;
            document.getElementById('test3').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
            result3 = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('test2').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
            result2 = 0;
            document.getElementById('test3').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
            result3 = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = result2;
         document.getElementById('result3').innerHTML = result3;

            }
</script>

<!--кнопка ОТПУСК -->

<button id="test3" onclick="myEvent3()">
    <p id="text3" style="position:absolute;color:black;top:6px;left:30px;font-size:30px;">ОТПУСК</p>
</button>

<div id="result3">0</div>

<!--СКРИПТ для кнопок вкл, выкл -->
<script>
    let result3 = 0;
    let myEvent3 = function()
    {
        if (result3 == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('test2').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
            result2 = 0;
            document.getElementById('test3').style.backgroundColor = '#3aff3a';
            result3 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('test2').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
            result2 = 0;
            document.getElementById('test3').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
            result3 = 0;
        }
       document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = result2;
         document.getElementById('result3').innerHTML = result3;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ООо спасибо ,за помощь)